# How to send parameters in datatables in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, datatable

I have included given code

```
drawUserTable = $('#user-table').DataTable({
    "dom": '<"search-box"r><"H"lf>t<"F"ip>',
    "bSort": false,
    "scrollCollapse": true,
    "responsive": true,
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": drawUserDataTableUrl,
    'fnServerParams':{
      'name': "dinshaw",
      'test': '022'
    },
    "columns": [
      {
        "class": "name",
        "id": "user_id",
        "data": "id"
      },
      {
        "class": "test",
        "id": "user_test",
        "data": "test"
      }
    ],
    tableTools: {
      "deferRender": true
    }    
  });
```

I want to send extra params with data table so I had used fnServerParams but its not working  it gives me error

> DataTables warning: table id=user-table - Cannot reinitialise
>   DataTable. For more information about this error, please see
>   http://datatables.net/tn/3

I have gone through given error link also but not getting how solve it out. Am I sending  params ina wrong way. Please guide me how to send params in datatable.

Comment: You can try the docs: http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/server-side ...Search fnServerParams and click on: `Show Details`

Comment: You might want to see the possible causes of this error through the link given. By the way, you're mixing the old 1.9 syntax and the 1.10 syntax, refer to https://www.datatables.net/upgrade/1.10 for more information on syntax changes.

Answer (score 3):

In reference to [this](https://github.com/antillas21/ajax-datatables-rails/issues/93).

This is what you need to do in order to pass in an options hash to the datatable class:

In your view, your table code should look like this:

```
<table data-source="<%= comments_path(current_user: current_user, format: :json) %>">

...
</table>
```

after this, you can access the current_user object in your datatable class as options[:current_user], example:

```
class MyDatatable < AjaxDatatablesRails::Base
  # other methods here
  def get_raw_records
    MyResource.where(user_id: options[:current_user].id)
  end
end
```

also don't forget to update controller side

```
def datatable
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.json { render json: MyDatatable.new(view_context , {current_user: current_user}) }
    end
end
```

Comment: Or please have a look at http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/callbacks#fnServerData

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
...
ajax: 
  url: drawUserDataTableUrl 
  data: (d) -> 
    d.name = "dinshaw" 
    d.test = '022'
    return
...
```

This is CoffeScript but you can easily transform it into plane JavaScript. More on that you can read [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data).